# How to get unique sets of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine people were asked their favorite color and their answers stored in a DataFrame (Person - Color). Some people name only one color, some -- more. I need to find unique combinations (sets) of colors.

```
import pandas as pd

data_list=['black',
           'red',
           'red',
           'black',
           'red',
           'white',
           'blue',
           'blue',
           'purple',
           'black',
           'green',
           'white',
           'black',
           'blue',
           'red',
          ]
names_list=['Michael',
            'Michael',
            'Tony',
            'Tony',
            'Helen',
            'Margo',
            'Max',
            'John',
            'Roxanne',
            'Roxanne',
            'Roxanne',
            'Marla',
            'Jack',
            'Jack',
            'Jack',
           ]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=zip(names_list, data_list), columns=['Person', 'Colors'])
```

I tried grouping the colors accordingly:

```
df.groupby('Names').agg({'Colors': pd.unique})
```

The output would be

```
                         Colors
Person
Helen                     [red]
Jack         [black, blue, red]
John                     [blue]
Margo                   [white]
Marla                   [white]
Max                      [blue]
Michael            [black, red]
Roxanne  [purple, black, green]
Tony               [red, black]
```

So I need one final aggregation of colors and I have no idea how to achieve it. Another iteration of pd.unique() doesn't work because sets are non-hashable. Converting sets to tuples doesn't work either because (black, red) is different from (red, black).
In the end I expect a result of

```
[red]
[black, blue, red]
[blue]
[white]
[black, red]
[purple, black, green]
```

(order doesn't matter)
Then I'll try to get some statistics like "how much people named only blue color their favorite and how much named red and black" but first thing first, I need to get all unique combinations of colors in a set.
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: what if you drop the duplicates once you reach that step? ```df.groupby('Person').agg({'Colors': pd.unique})['Colors'].drop_duplicates()```.  Unless i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a new column with a joined string of all the colors:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Names').agg({'Colors': pd.unique})
df_grouped['Colors str'] = [''.join(sorted(color_list)) for color_list in df_grouped['Colors']]

# drop duplicate color combinations: 
df_grouped = df_grouped.drop_duplicates(subset=['Colors str'])

print(f"Unique color combinations: \n {df_grouped ['Colors']}")
```

Comment: Thank you. It gets the job done and it looks better than mine solution:
(I've moved to the next step: count the persons with same colors named. Oh, and someone named the same color twice and I need to analyze that too hence list -> sorted -> tuple call)  
`df=pd.DataFrame(data=zip(names_list, data_list), columns=['Person', 'Colors'])

def test_func(data_in):
    return(tuple(list(sorted(data_in))))

df_grouped=df.groupby('Person').agg({'Colors': test_func})
df_grouped['p']=df_grouped.index #Person became an index
print(df_grouped.groupby('Colors').count())`